# Filtrar queryset por grupo

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Tengo un modelo que se llama ColaNotificaciones.

```
class ColaNotificaciones(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('remitente', 'destinatario', 'asunto','producto'),)

    remitente = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    destinatario = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    asunto = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    is_email = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_notificacion = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    f_publi = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    producto = models.IntegerField(default = None)
```

De este modelo filtro los que sean is_email = False.

Una vez obtenga el queryset quiero volver a filtrar por producto, para obtener un nuevo queryset en el que salgan todas las notificaciones de un mismo producto, para generar un correo en el que sepan cuantas notificaciones tiene y que remitentes han notificado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lo que te voy a platear aquí te devolverá una lista con las notificaciones por producto y otra con el numero de notificaciones por remitente

```
not_por_producto = ColaNotificaciones.objects.filter(is_email=False).values('producto').annotate(contador=Count('producto'))
```

esa consulta te devolver el número de notificaciones que hay por producto

y de la misma manera para nº de notificaciones por remitente

```
not_por_remitente = ColaNotificaciones.objects.filter(is_email=False).values('remitente').annotate(contador=Count('remitente'))
```

este es el link de la [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/)

Comment: era exactamente lo que buscaba, muchas gracias

Comment: Me alegra haber ayudado

Answer (score 0):

Puedes efectuar ambos filtros en un mismo queryset:

```
mi_filtro = ColaNotificaciones.objects.filter(is_email = False, product='Numero del producto que necesitas filtrar sin comillas')
```

Me confirmas si te funciona

Comment: no puedo hacer eso ya que tengo miles de productos, digamos que quiero extraerlos por bloques. No sé si hay alguna manera de extraerlos por grupos en un for por ejemplo.

Comment: Si, podria ser una solución, pero entonces de donde extraes la lista de productos ?, en el model lo tiens como un campo tipo entero, pensaste en crearlo como un modelo aparte y convertirlo en foranea ?, confirmame ambas preguntas para seguirte ayudando y modificar la respuesta.